# Unable to click on a link inside textview message on android mobile app-Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

Anyone help on this....

> `code`

I want to access the hyperlink within my text as depicted in the pic :

[image: hyperlinked text in message]

Notes:
I tried directly clicking in text by using id but didnt worked.
I tried using scrollTo() but still it didnt worked.
I tried with linkText even that didnt worked.

Answer (score 1):

`clickable` is set to `false`. You have to set it `true` in xml file and later on handle `onClick` event in your activity class

Comment: talking in general, the `Url` in the text is anyway clicked, be the TextView clickable or not..isn't it?

Comment: @nullpointer if  `autoLink` is set to `web` in xml file then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: This text message is not developed  in our app..from our app this will be shared via whatsapp . Even i didnt get which xml ur talking about

Comment: @SudhakarMK I didn't get you. What do you mean that it is not developed in your app? If you have a *TextView* then it is normally located in *XML Layout File* where you can configure ceratain elements, such as: *TextView, Button and etc.* . You can as well configure this parameter in *Activity  class* .

Answer (score 0):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtv3o.png)  only you need to handle onclick listener in Android java file where you make reference the text of your xml like

```
 TextView mytext=(TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.ref of your TextView);
 mytext.setOnClickList();
```

Comment: could you please brief on this.. i tried your code i am seeing error to textview..i have attached screen shot

Comment: @SudhakarMK please send me screen shot of your error

Comment: Attached screen shot--

Comment: TextView mytext=(TextView)findviewbyid(text); 
    mytext.setOnClickList();